# Theoretical Procedure for Power Series Equation:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, summation, power-series, summation-method

If I have the following equation: \begin{equation}2c_0(x-1)+\sum_{k=2}^\infty[(c_{k-2}+2c_{k-1})(x-1)^k]+\sum_{k=0}^\infty[(c_{k+2}(k+2)(k+1)+kc_k+(k+1)c_{k+1}+c_k)(x-1)^k]=0 \end{equation}
I was wondering if it would reasonable that I can do the following: \begin{align}c_0&=0\\c_{k-2}+2c_{k+2}&=0\\ c_{k+2}(k+2)(k+1)+kc_k+(k+1)c_{k+1}+c_k&=0 \end{align}
Or do I need to combine the two summations first?

Comment: If $a+b=0$, it's not always the case that one of $a$ or $b$ must be $0$ (in which case both $a=b=0$). You really should combine all terms with the same degree, then deduce what the coefficients of those terms are. Also, is the $(x-1)^k$ factor in the second series not supposed to be outside the square brackets?

Comment: @user170231 Its supposed to be inside.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I didn't notice the other set of parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the series we set $k=1$ and $k=0$

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty[(c_{k+2}(k+2)(k+1)+kc_k+(k+1)c_{k+1}+c_k)(x-1)^k] $$
For $k=1$ we have the coefficient for $x-1$
$$(x-1)(6c_3+2c_1+2c_2)$$
You have to add that to the term $2c_0(x-1)$. So that:
$$(x-1)(6c_3+2c_1+2c_2+2c_0)=0$$
$$ (6c_3+2c_1+2c_2+2c_0)=0$$
$$\implies 3c_3+c_1+c_2+c_0=0$$

---

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty[(c_{k+2}(k+2)(k+1)+kc_k+(k+1)c_{k+1}+c_k)(x-1)^k] $$
For $k=0$
$$2c_2+c_1+c_0=0$$

To summarize you have two equalities for the coefficients. You can easily deduce that:
$$ 3c_3+c_1+c_2+c_0=0$$
$$ 3c_3-2c_2+c_2=0$$
$$c_2=3c_3$$
These are your equalities:
$$
\begin{cases}
c_2=3c_3 \\
2c_2+c_1+c_0=0
\end{cases}
$$
And the series:
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty[(c_{k-2}+2c_{k-1}+c_{k+2}(k+2)(k+1)+(k+1)c_{k+1}+c_k(k+1))(x-1)^k]=0 $$

Comment: You know I was afraid to keep asking what you meant before but then I hit a dead end and was confused. But thanks.

Comment: I spent most my morning trying to solve the problem.

Comment: No problem you 're welcome. We are to ask questions and help each other. @EnlightenedFunky

Comment: I know you have tried before to ask @EnlightenedFunky